Failed to query data using WHERE and IN clause on PHP MySQL with multiple ID
I'm using pure PHP and MySQL. And I'm a beginner PHP developer.
Let say I have this string that contains some IDs
$string = "123,46,78,000";

And I would like to query data by using this value to this query
Select *
FROM my_table
WHERE id IN (?)

I've been trying by using this way
$string = "123,46,78,000";
$str_arr = explode(',', $string);
$new_str = null;
foreach ($str_arr as $key=>$value) {
  if ($key == (count($str_arr)-1)) {
    $new_str .= $value;
  } else {
    $new_str .= $value.",";
  }
}

But it always return as an 0 records.
Here is my full codes
$query = "SELECT *
           FROM my_table
           WHERE id IN (?)";

        //prepare
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        //sanitize
        $this->id     = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->province));

        //bind params
        if ($this->id) {
            $str_arr = explode(',', $this->id);
            $new_str = null;
            foreach ($str_arr as $key=>$value) {
                if ($key == (count($str_arr)-1)) {
                    $new_str .= $value;
                } else {
                    $new_str .= $value.",";
                }
            }
           $stmt->bindParam(1, $new_str);
        }

        
        //execute
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;

How do I get all data with various ID?

start from exploding this string into array

@YourCommonSense I have attached my codes including the exploding string.

the rest is in the answer already linked at the top

Your usage of htmlspecialchars() is inappropriate and potentially problematic. htmlspecialchars() is an output filter, only to be used specifically when outputting data into a HTML document. It is designed only to help protect against XSS. It should not be used at any other time, such as when receiving input data -in the worst case it can change or corrupt your data unnecessarily in that situation. It also has nothing to do with preventing SQL injection. See when to use htmlspecialchars() function?
